# Updating django models

Tags: python, django

I added a new field to an existing model. When I use the command "manage.py makemigrations myapp" I get the following error:

```
You are trying to add a non-nullable field 'slug' to post without a default. we can not do that < the database needs something to populate existing rows>.
```

What should be the default value for the new field slug? Here is my model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 100, null = False, blank = False)
    body = models.TextField()
    dateCreated = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: That's normal behavior...

Comment: @mevius but my model does not updates

Comment: @Alexander Think of it this way -- how CAN it update? What can the script possibly decide to put in this new field besides None/NULL? And you said this is not allowed (it's both unique constrained and non-nullable).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add a not-null field to an existing model without a default value. If you *must* make it not-null, you should:

1. Add the field using `null=True`
2. Migrate your database
3. Populate existing rows
4. Remove `null=True`
5. Migrate again

Comment: This is exactly right. This is normally done with 2-3 migrations (depending on whether #3 is a "data migration" or script or done manually or whatever).

Answer (score 2):

This is because you are trying to create a migration with a non nullable field, that's why it is asking to provide a default value. Since it is a `slug` field, I would set it to `null=True` and `blank=False` and try again.

Also, you may want to set [prepopulated_fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.prepopulated_fields) in your Django `admin.py` file.

PS: You don't have to specify `null = False` and `blank = False` since those values are the default ones.