# Can't make migration in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

I can't migrate this model in Django

```py
class ApprovedCourse(models.Model):
    course_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    provider_college = models.ManyToManyField('processes.College', related_name="provider_college")
    prerequisites = models.ManyToManyField('ApprovedCourse', related_name="courses_that_need_this_course",null=True)
    both_needs = models.ManyToManyField('ApprovedCourse', related_name="courses_required_for_this_course",null=True)
    number_of_course_units = models.IntegerField()
    course_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class SemesterCourse(models.Model):
    approved_course=models.ForeignKey('ApprovedCourse', on_delete=models.CASCADE , null=True, related_name='approved_course')
    class_day_and_time = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    exam_date_and_time = jmodels.jDateTimeField()
    exam_location = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    course_professor = models.ForeignKey('users.Professor', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name="professor_course")
    course_capacity = models.IntegerField()
    current_semester = models.ForeignKey('processes.Semester', on_delete=models.SET_NULL,  null=True, related_name="semester_course")
```

When I want to add approved_course field and `makemigration` it shows this message

> Please select a fix:
>
> 1. Provide a one-off default now (will be set on all existing rows with a null value for this column)
> 2. Quit and manually define a default value in models.py.
>    Select an option:

How can I solve it?

Comment: Well what is not clear about the prompt?

Answer (score 0):

It is an unnamed specification in Django and SQL databases at large IMO. [Django can't add a new non null-able field by itself without specifying a default.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66785579/16770846) Even if there are no rows in the database already, as long as a migration has already been made for the model earlier, adding a new field to the model and making a new migration will require a One-off default value to be specified for the field added or you can put a default directly in code.
[A ticket was raised for this actually but it was closed with a resolve of "Cleanup/optimization (wontfix)"](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/30390)

Answer (score -2):

You can migrate your created models to back admin using the following command:

```
python manage.py makemigration
python manage.py migrate
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**