# cant create django superuser when User model extends Abstract User

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to create a custom user model by inheriting from AbstractUser.Only issue is that I am not able to create a SuperUser in my terminal. It prompts me to enter my username and then throws this error after that

> django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: api_user.name

this is what my user model looks like:

```js
class User(AbstractUser):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=200, default="")
    dob = models.DateField("Date Of Birth",blank=True, default=None)
    profileImg = models.ImageField(upload_to='frontend/src/assets/profileImgs/',blank=True)
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
    USERNAME_FIELD = "username"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
    
    def was_published_recently(self):
        return self.createdAt >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

    def to_dict(self):
        return{
        "id": self.id,
        "name": self.name,
        "email": self.email,
        "password": self.password,
        "dob": self.dob,
        "profileImg": os.path.basename(self.profileImg.name),
        "createdAt": self.createdAt,
        }
```

I am really new to django so I am not sure what am I doing wrong here

Comment: did you migrate?

Comment: I cant migrate, I keep getting this error everytime:
>It is impossible to add a non-nullable field 'name' to user without specifying a default. This is because the database needs something to populate existing rows.

Comment: You have migrated already once before. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77475738/16770846).

Answer (score 0):

First Register app and then  In settings.py AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'your_app.User'
the makemigrations and then migrate
her your field some field is required  name so you have to override the base manager

so you have to override the usermanager() and add name to while creating or you can simply change
name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=true, blank=True)
and migrate